# sed command to replace all last lines with some new multi line strings after getting second pattern

Tags: linux, unix, sed

I want to write a program to change systems ip address from dhcp/static to static only. my original file's contents will be either this

```
some initial text

[ipv6]
method=auto

[ipv4]
method=static
dns=8.8.8.8;
addresses1=192.168.1.10;24;192.168.1.1;
```

or it may be like this,

```
some initial text

[ipv6]
method=auto

[ipv4]
method=auto
```

Now, i want to change after [ipv4] pattern, so that after editing my file should looks like this

```
some initial text

[ipv6]
method=auto

[ipv4]
method=static
dns=8.8.8.8;4.4.4.4;
addresses1=192.168.1.20;24;192.168.1.1;
```

Comment: Or, in `sed`, `sed -e '/^\[ipv4\]/,/^method=/{ s/method=.*/method=static/; }'`.

Comment: @melpomene: does your Perl give `method=staticauto` (or `method=staticstatic` in the output?  Do you need `perl -pi -e '/^\[ipv4\]/ .. s/^method=.*/method=static/'` ?

Comment: Thank you @melpomene. I tried but not getting what i want. i want to delete all lines after [ipv4] and after that i add two more lines dns and addresses1. but in your answer, it only replaces the text between [ipv4] and method, not delete the last two lines. if i add two lines then last dns and addresses lines are shifted downwards, it is not going to delete.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Oh, indeed. It's broken.

Comment: Thnx @JonathanLeffler i did it with some change { sed -e '/^\[ipv4\]/,/^addresses1=/{ s/dns.*//; s/add.*//; s/method=.*/method=static\ndns=8.8.8.8;4.4.4.4;\naddresses1=192.168.1.10;24;192.168.1.125;/; }' TargetFile }

Comment: Glad you've got it resolved.  I think your description of what you want is a little misleading.  It would seem that you want to replace all the text in the block after an `[ipv4]` label line with three lines of data.  That's mildly fiddly unless blank lines always separate blocks, and blank lines only separate blocks (never appear within a block).  There are ways to do that of greater or lesser fiddliness and robustness, depending on your choice of language.  The more systematic the format of the files, the easier it is. If the last entry in the file has a blank line at the end, it is simpler.

Comment: now the problem is to pass the above command using pssh. coded in python programming language. os.system("echo '123456' | pssh -H 192.168.1.10 -l root -A -i 'sed -e '/^\[ipv4\]/,/^addresses1=/{ s/dns.*//; s/add.*//; s/method=.*/method=static\ndns=8.8.8.8;4.4.4.4;\naddresses1=192.168.1.10;24;192.168.1.125;/; }' TargetFile'"). In python, it doesn't allow me to pass the same above commands.

Comment: In python, the string after semicolumn ";" takes as a new command or single quotes not able to pass through pssh even using backslash "\". nothing is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a Perl solution.  It sets the record delimiter to 2 newlines, so paragraphs are read.  If the paragraph contains `[ipv4]`, replace the input with the replacement.  Replace `data` with the name of your file, or with `"$@"` and make it into a shell script.  Add `-i` as an option to Perl if you want to overwrite files (don't do that until you've tested it).

```
perl -pe '
my $replacement = qq"[ipv4]\n" .
                    "method=static\n" .
                    "dns=8.8.8.8;4.4.4.4;\n" .
                    "addresses1=192.168.1.20;24;192.168.1.1;\n\n";
$/ = "\n\n";
$_ = $replacement if (m/^\[ipv4\]$/m);' data
```

There are many alternative ways of writing that code; I make no claims other than "it works for me".

Given the text of your question as the input, the output is:

```
I want to write a program to change systems ip address from dhcp/static to static only. my original file's contents will be either this

some initial text

[ipv6]
method=auto

[ipv4]
method=static
dns=8.8.8.8;4.4.4.4;
addresses1=192.168.1.20;24;192.168.1.1;

or it may be like this,

some initial text

[ipv6]
method=auto

[ipv4]
method=static
dns=8.8.8.8;4.4.4.4;
addresses1=192.168.1.20;24;192.168.1.1;

Now, i want to change after [ipv4] pattern, so that after editing my file should looks like this

some initial text

[ipv6]
method=auto

[ipv4]
method=static
dns=8.8.8.8;4.4.4.4;
addresses1=192.168.1.20;24;192.168.1.1;
```